# What's the proper way to dynamically resize a UITextField while keeping it centered as text is entered?

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextfield, autolayout

Given a textfield, I want it to dynamically resize horizontally as the user types in text.  I also want it stay centered in its superview.  I've stumbled on a way to do this but it seems contrived and unlikely to be the right approach.  I feel like I'm missing something simple here like an attribute of a textfield or a control or some protocol I'm not familiar with.

In Interface Builder I have a UITextField with text "__".  It has two constraints, 100 pixels from the top and centered vertically.  The ViewController is the delegate for the textfield and the Editing Changed event is sent to **textFieldAction:**

```
- (IBAction)textFieldAction:(UITextField *)sender {
    NSString *s = sender.text;
    CGSize newSize = [sender sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = sender.frame;
    newFrame.size = newSize;
    sender.frame = newFrame;
    sender.text = s;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.text = @"";
    return YES;
}
```

The oddities are

- if I don't set the text to @"" in **textFieldShouldBeginEditing:** the textfield doesn't dynamically resize
- if I don't reassign the text in **textFieldAction:** the textfield  dynamically resizes but doesn't dynamically remained centered.

In both cases the layout is eventually adjusted when the textfield resigns first responder.

Is this the right way to get a dynamically resizing and centered textfield, or a hack?

Comment: can you set some breakpoints or logs and determine the seqeunce in which these methods are being called? most specifically, is textViewAction: called once or twice when you tap on the textfield? if twice, who is sender?

Comment: textFieldAction: is called once for each key press.  The sender is the textField.  textFieldShouldBeginEditing: is called when I tap in the textField, textFieldAction: is called once per tap and textFieldShouldReturn: is called when I tap "return".

Comment: After more experimentation it seems **textFieldShouldBeginEditing:** only needs one line: `sender.text = sender.text;`  That string reassignment is necessary but sufficient.  The hack is looking pretty attractive.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a hack to me, but i cant test my own suggestion right now.
If I tried to keep a textfield centered during the user input, i would use

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField)shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

in the UITextFieldDelegate protocol and do the calculation there.
While you are at it, you could also try `[textfield sizeToFit]` to get rid of the caculation altogether.

You could also get rid of the constraints and just set `textfield.center.x = [[UIScreen mainScreen] screensize].width / 2` or `textfield.center.x = textfield.superview.center.x` to keep it centered horizontally. Or you stick with autolayout, im just not that big of a fan.

From the docs of textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

```
Return Value:  
YES if the specified text range should be replaced; otherwise, NO to keep the old text.

Discussion:  
The text field calls this method whenever the user types a new character in the text field or deletes an existing character.`
```

So be sure to return YES, and let me know how it turns out if you try it.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried your suggestion, but the effect of using  **textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:** is almost the same as using the action.  If the text string isn't set to @"" in **textFieldShouldBeginEditing** and reassigned in **textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:** the textfield doesn't dynamically resize.

Comment: By the way, I did try your suggestion to replace the frame resizing calculation with **sizeToFit** and that is an improvement.  Thanks.